# What if the answer to a question is "no, it is not possible"

Tags: discussion, answers

If the proper answer to a question is: "No, what you are asking to do cannot be done" is that a valid way to answer it?

Here is the question I am wondering about: [How do I make git automatically open the mergetool if there is a merge conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032265/how-do-i-make-git-automatically-open-the-mergetool-if-there-is-a-merge-conflict/17693871#17693871)

I offered the correct answer (No, you can't do it yet) and then offered an alternative workaround that accomplished what they were looking for.  How could I have answered the question better?  Should I have offered the answer (no) and the workaround as two separate answers?

Comment: Yes, and this question is  duplicate. Looking for the target...

Comment: Yes, I believe my question could be a duplicate.  Is there any special case for workarounds here?

Comment: @onionjake You are of course welcome to include them.  You are not *obligated* to provide a workaround.

Comment: @Servy if my workaround was unacceptable, would that make my answer invalid?

Comment: @onionjake That would be a judgement that each reader would need to make when evaluating the question.  There is no concrete answer in the general case.

Comment: @derp And a bad/unsafe/hacky workaround could well make an answer unhelpful in the general case, not just one person's case.

Comment: @Servy: Which is why such an answer should prominently and clearly state the caveats, in which case it stays a good answer (unless there's a way to avoid those pitfalls).

Comment: Would it be more appropriate to offer the answer "No, it is not possible" and the answer with the workaround separately?

Comment: @Deduplicator As I said, it's going to be entirely dependent on context.  Trying to give rules for the general case just isn't productive.

Comment: I don't think so. The "no, not possible" (with proof) part would stand alone as a (not very good) answer, but the workaround needs some motivation, namely that what was asked is impossible and why.